# Unity2D + Compiz make Chromium tabs unmovable

Tags: compiz, unity-2d, chromium, compositing

I changed Metacity to Compiz. Everything works great.

However, when I use Chromium, as I hold the tab to organize them, the tab can't merge to the original window. So later on, it opens a new window.

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: I'm at least glad, from your question, I now realize it's related to Unity2D. I made the change not too long ago and didn't make the connection.